# Bootstrap is adding a white line when going from col-sm to col-xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When my page re-sizes from SM to XS it is adding a white line (almost like a margin space) and I don't know why. If I add a style="margin-top: -1px" it goes away but then messes up the rest of the grid structure. Any ideas as to what is causing this? Below is the code, if you run the snippet and shrink the window you'll see the line appear.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <title>JPT Email Template Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
      <div class ="col-xs-0 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 bg-primary text-center">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://pages.jerusalemprayerteam.org/rs/591-HWU-361/images/foz-logo.png" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 text-center bg-primary">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://i.imgur.com/i131rzd.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class"col-xs-0 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens cause you do not use bootstrap properly, you have chosen an option of adding extra `divs` for offset and it's wrong. Bootstrap has `offset` for this cases:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    Your content
</div>
```

Do not use those extra `divs` for offset, one of those is giving you this `1px`

Comment: Thank you for this. I am still new to web development and I appreciate the critic. This fixed my issue completely. I will go in and adjust my other sites as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Columns have a min-height of 1px. So the below creates the white line. Try using `.hidden-xs` instead.

```
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to previous answers, Bootstrap has not class "col-xs-0".